# create another muti dimentional array from exsisting array and sort a muti dimentional array

Tags: php, function, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have question about php arrays. i have array like $data.

```
$data=array(array('a'=>'1','b'=>'2','c'=>'3','d'=>'4'),array('a'=>'5','b'=>'6','c'=>'7','d'=>'8'),array('a'=>'9','b'=>'10','c'=>'11','d'=>'12'));
```

i want to get only a,c,d element and create another multi dimensional array like $data1.

```
$data1=array(
        array('a'=>'1','c'=>'3','d'=>'4'),
            array('a'=>'5','c'=>'7','d'=>'8'),
            array('a'=>'9','c'=>'11','d'=>'12')         
        );
```

as a next step i wanted to sort $data1 array by first value of d elements then by value of c elements and finally by a elements and get array like $data2.

```
$data2=array(           
            array('a'=>'9','c'=>'11','d'=>'12')
            array('a'=>'5','c'=>'7','d'=>'8'),
            array('a'=>'1','c'=>'3','d'=>'4')
            );
```

i need little bit explained answer to each step. i'm stuck in here this problem. i want help..
and are there any php array function available for get $data1 array from $data easily?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, array functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php Foreach: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php Working with arrays: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+working+with+arrays

Comment: PHP arrays are nested, not multi-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in your case..

```
$data=array(array('a'=>'1','b'=>'2','c'=>'3','d'=>'4'),array('a'=>'5','b'=>'6','c'=>'7','d'=>'8'),array('a'=>'9','b'=>'10','c'=>'11','d'=>'12'));
$data1 = array();

//getting data1 by removing the b's 

foreach($data as $d){
   while(list($k,$v) = each($d)){
    if($k == "b"){
        unset($d[$k]);
    }
}
array_push($data1, $d);
}

//Sorting the arrays
foreach($data1 as $key => $value){
  $ds[$key] = $value["d"];
  $cs[$key] = $value["c"];
  $as[$key] = $value["a"];
}

array_multisort($ds, SORT_DESC, $cs, SORT_DESC, $as, SORT_DESC, $data1);
print_r($data1);
```

This will print:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [a] => 9
        [c] => 11
        [d] => 12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [a] => 5
        [c] => 7
        [d] => 8
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [a] => 1
        [c] => 3
        [d] => 4
    )
```

)

Dins

Comment: your answer is very helpful and clear. thank you. and i appreciate other answers and responses... too...